# Creating a table of cells with JS and trying to access them individually

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have an empty table which is filled with content when a button is pressed. Each table row will only have one cell in it and the content of the cell is string. These strings are contained in an array beforehand. So when user presses the button, this happens:

```
function buttonClicked()
{
    for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
    {
        table = document.getElementById("my_table");
        row = table.insertRow(0);
        cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.innerHTML = list[i];
    }
}
```

The table is being created as planned, but the problem comes when I try to access those cells individually by mouse when the program is running. The goal is to be able to click a content and then the program should show a certain image unique to the clicked content of the table. I don't know how to access those cells individually because JS creates them when the program starts. So there is nothing to be manipulated in the HTML-code except the empty table tags. Please let me know if this is even remotely correct way to do something like this. I know this may be a very simple problem, but I'm novice coder and didn't even know how to formulate a search on google/stackoverflow about this problem because it's so hard to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the click handler on element creation:

```js
const list = [
  "//placehold.it/60x60/0bf",
  "//placehold.it/60x60/f0b",
];

const populate_my_table = () => list.forEach((item, i) => {

    const row = my_table.insertRow(-1), // Append to table using -1
      cell = row.insertCell(0),
      img = document.createElement("img"); // "img" or the selector you need

    img.src = item;
    img.addEventListener("click", evt => {
      console.log( evt.target.src ); // Do something on click
    });
    cell.textContent = `IMAGE:${i+1}`;
    cell.appendChild(img);
});

document.getElementById("my_button").addEventListener("click", populate_my_table);
```

```html
<button id="my_button">LOAD IMAGES</button>
<table id="my_table"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the cells in a couple of ways depending on what you mean by "access".

First, you can use the [DOM Table API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) and specify the row index and the cell index to work with and then you can interact with and "access" rows and/or cells in the table at any time you wish:

```js
// Button to make table
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);

// Table data items
let list = ["Red", "White", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"];

// Declare the variable outside of the loop so that you don't have to
// re-scan for it over and over.
let table = document.getElementById("my_table"); 

function buttonClicked()
{
    for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
    {
        let row = table.insertRow(0);
        let cell = row.insertCell(0);

        // Use .textContent when the content isn't HTML as it's quicker and safer
        cell.textContent = list[i]; 
    }
      
    
   // Let's get our hands on the "Blue" cell
   let blue = table.rows[2].cells[0]; 

   // Now, do whatever you want with it
   blue.style.fontWeight = "bold";
   blue.classList.add("Blue");
}
```

```css
table, td { border:1px solid black; margin:1em; }
.Red { background-color: #f00; }
.White { background-color: #fff; }
.Blue { background-color: #33f; color:#fff; }
.Yellow { background-color: #ff0; }
.Green { background-color: #0f0; }
```

```html
<button type="button">Make Table</button>
<table id="my_table"></table>
```

And second, you can set up event callbacks on the cells as you make them, so the user interactions can be reacted to:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);

let list = ["Red", "White", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"];
let table = document.getElementById("my_table"); // Declare the variable outside of the loop

function buttonClicked()
{
    for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
    {
        let row = table.insertRow(0);
        let cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.textContent = list[i]; // Use .textContent when the content isn't HTML
        cell.addEventListener("click", function(){
          // In this context, "this" refers to the element that triggered
          // the event we are handling -- the cell you clicked.
          alert("You clicked the: " + this.textContent + " cell.");
          this.classList.add(this.textContent);
        });
    }
}
```

```css
table, td { border:1px solid black; margin:1em; }
.Red { background-color: #f00; }
.White { background-color: #fff; }
.Blue { background-color: #33f; color:#fff; }
.Yellow { background-color: #ff0; }
.Green { background-color: #0f0; }
```

```html
<button type="button">Make Table</button>
<table id="my_table"></table>
```

But, the last example sets up a number of event listeners and that can impact performance. Instead, we can set up a listener on the `table` and because [events "bubble"](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing), clicks on the cells will bubble up to the table where we can intercept the event. We can then find out where the event originated with `event.target` and act accordingly. This is called ["Event Delegation"](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) and is better, not only because less event handlers need to be registered, but also because any new cells that get created later are already going to participate in the event process.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);

let list = ["Red", "White", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"];
let table = document.getElementById("my_table"); // Declare the variable outside of the loop

// Set up the event at the table level instead of at each cell
table.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  alert("You clicked the: " + event.target.textContent + " cell.");
  event.target.classList.add(event.target.textContent);
});

function buttonClicked()
{
    for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
    {
        let row = table.insertRow(0);
        let cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.textContent = list[i]; // Use .textContent when the content isn't HTML
    }
}
```

```css
table, td { border:1px solid black; margin:1em; }
.Red { background-color: #f00; }
.White { background-color: #fff; }
.Blue { background-color: #33f; color:#fff; }
.Yellow { background-color: #ff0; }
.Green { background-color: #0f0; }
```

```html
<button type="button">Make Table</button>
<table id="my_table"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#my_table tr td').onClick(function(){
    console.log('click in cell');
});
```